# Packer changed memory in IDA?

Tags: ida, packers

I'm trying to analyze one binary protected by HASP. Since it is pretty old binary (2008) I managed to run it in IDA and it unpacked in memory. When I do tracing + take memory snapshot and reanalyze it, the view of functions I get does not make any sense.

[image]

How is it possible that instructions are skipped? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at 64bit code disassembled as 32bit code.

```
dec eax
sub esp, 28h
```

is the byte pattern `48 83 ec 28`, which is

```
sub rsp, 28h
```

As a rule of thumb, if you see a lot of `dec eax` out of place, you're wrongly disassembling 64bit as 32bit code.

Comment: I'm running 32 bit binary on win 7 x64. Is that the reason?

Comment: btw this on the right side is output from IDA trace, so I guess that it is actually showing what is executed. Probably the problem is that this binary is self-unpacking and then something happens there.